# Only a small subset of contacts is synced in iOS 9

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts, ios, google-sync

Thanks to the help I got here, my [iOS 9 contacts are synced with my GMail account pretty well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208175/how-to-force-a-sync-update-between-gmail-contacts-and-iphone-with-ios-9) - the sync works, but is not immediate.

I would like to sync my contacts to iCloud as well, in order to be able to call a contact from FaceTime on my Macbook Pro with El Capitan 10.11.1.

I have enabled contact sync under iCloud on my device:

[image]

However, only 44 contacts are synced. There seems to be nothing special about them - some are old, some are new, and they were all synced from GMail.

Any idea how to sync these contacts to iCloud?

Comment: can you see your entire contact list on icloud.com -> contacts.

Comment: @maetsoh Done that, I see only 44 contacts out of the hundreds I have in my phone.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your iCloud account (from settings -> mail,contacts,calendar), restarting the phone and adding the iCloud again. This will force the data that is not already synced to sync.

Comment: @maetsoh Do you mean `settings` - `iCloud`, and unchecking / checking contacts, mail etc? Will that *delete* the iCloud account?

Comment: No, you should have a copy of your iCloud account in Settings - >  Mail, Contacts, Calendar. This is the account you'll have to delete (delete button in the bottom of the screen)

Comment: Go to : 
1 http://i.stack.imgur.com/edmyE.jpg
2 http://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Lz3.jpg
3 http://i.stack.imgur.com/5r6hQ.jpg

and from the same screen as 2 (ie Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars) click add an account and add the iCloud account you just deleted. this should work fine

Comment: @maetsoh Thanks, didn't work for me - same 44 contacts synced.